# How do I dynamically change a template URL in an Angular JS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I know that there's a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl) but it's not quite what I am looking for. The ng-include alows me to dynamically change the path but then I can't access scope variables.

Basically I would like to dynamically assign a template URL to a directive through an AJAX call. Unfortunately I can't seem to bind the directive attribute to an actual scope variable.

```
app.directive('appsdirective', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl : function(elem,attrs) {
            // attrs.templateUrl contains "app.appPath" rather than the content itself
            return attrs.templateUrl;
        },
        restrict : 'EA',
        scope : false
    }
});

<appsdirective template-url="{{app.appPath}}"></appsdirective>
```

$scope.app is a main controller variable that is undefined at the beginning but gets initialized later through an AJAX request. I also tried manually initializing the variable but it didn't help and I get this obvious error in the console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/%7B%7Bapp.appPath%7D%7D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs directive set template url dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397424/angularjs-directive-set-template-url-dynamically) - specifically check out the second answer with manipulating ng-include.

Comment: The second answer uses ng-include which I am trying to avoid. The first one uses the templateUrl function but it doesn't seem to work in the current version of AngularJS.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by I can't access the scope vars though? Also will using the ng-if to not render until you have the ajax call back not work either?

Comment: Inside the directive I am accessing lots of parent controller variables but when I use the ng-include solution the binding stops working.

Comment: Ok got it, and the ng-if won't work either?

Comment: The ng-if looks outdated from the comment but I may be wrong. Btw to be more precise with the ng-include solution I can't access directive scope from the parent scope (basically ng-model doesn't work anymore in the directive).

Comment: give the ng-if a shot before you rule it out :)